# How do i validate haproxy.cfg using an API and a parser in Golang?

Tags: api, rest, validation, go, haproxy

I need to create a REST API to validate the HAProxy configurations and check for any syntax errors and all.
I need to use this https://github.com/haproxytech/config-parser in order to parse and validate.
However, i can't find a way to do so!

Comment: They have an example in readme https://github.com/haproxytech/config-parser#example

Comment: Yea, but there are a few errors I’m not able to resolve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.